# How to force $animate to cache a new version of an element?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm using 1.2.6 ng-animate on ng-view. In app.run, I'm calling a service method that applies classes to the ng-view element using jQuery initially, then changes the classes again on $viewContentLoaded. Problem is that after route is changed and a new view is loaded, $animate seems to keep a cached version of the element that existed when I first applied a different class, so it sort of rolls back to the original element version.

Is there a way to force $animate to update it's cached version manually? $apply() doesn't seem to have an effect. Thank you for any hints.

Comment: "I'm calling a service method that applies classes to the ng-view element using jQuery initially". This sounds like an unusual design (and possibly poor/over complicated). Can you post the code that does this, and ideally a Plunker of a minimal version that does this?

Comment: It's more of a general question about the possibility of updating $animate manually as there are other ways to achieve the same the same thing that my specific case requires (ng-hide/show). As with any other form of DOM modification outside of the "Angular World", where you have to manually trigger the digest cycle for Angular to notice DOM changes (let's say for 3rd party plugins), this seems to be relevant to the more or less automated ng-animate. I'll create an example of this behavior if I get some time soon. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: explain why you need to use jQUery to change the classes at run time and why you can't do it by working with a model in angular.

Comment: I can, read the comment above. The question is different.

Comment: Same issue here. If i use the $animate and the use the history.back() to move back to that page, the partial does not clear like it would have on a fresh load. Did you find any resolution to thsi ?

Comment: That sounds like your issue is a bit different, but no, haven't found any further info on this.